# Cancel windows login

Tags: windows-10, login

When trying to login to windows sometimes I remember during the login that I used the wrong password. Windows then tries for a very long time to check the **wrong** password if it is correct.

[Description](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100323-00/?p=14513) of the proces.

How can I cancel/stop the login process when I remember I used the wrong password?

This is for my *live.com* account.

Comment: Is this a domain account on a work computer, a personal account on your own computer, or perhaps a Microsoft account?

Comment: @music2myear +1 -> will update the question

Comment: You can't; but it should be nearly instantaneous all the same;  since your accounts password is stored locally even when using a local account connected to a MS account

Comment: @Ramhound usually when using the correct password it logs in within a second or so, but when accidently using another password it tries and tries between a minute to sometimes even 5 minutes

Comment: Actually, when an incorrect password is entered for a Live account Windows first checks its local cache, and then if there is not a match, it must attempt to phone home to find out if the password has changed. If the entered password matches the local cache it allows the login, and then attempts to check for updates in the background. If there is an update then it will prompt you to lock the computer and unlock it using the new password.

Comment: From what I've seen around the 'net this is a known symptom (hesitant to say "issue") and is the way the system is designed. To allow the process to be escaped early could have security implications, so I'm not sure at this point if there is a way to escape it or shorten the default delay.

Comment: At least some of the delay is based on the principle of slowing bad password attempts to delay dictionary attacks, even before you actually get into the multiple bad passwords and locked accounts settings.

Comment: One suggestion is to disable your internet (disconnect the network cable or turn off your wireless card) while the login attempt is proceeding. If the computer is no longer able to contact the Live login servers it should take the cache password as correct and dump you back to the login screen. Try this.

Comment: @music2myear Your comments are correct. It correctly describes the problem. But you solution would require me to turn of my WiFI, because I don't have access to disable the network cards when not signed-in.

Comment: Does your computer have a physical WiFi switch? Yea, the solution has its draw-backs, but if its the only solution (and based on a few minutes of Google-fu it is looking that way), it's at least a solution.

Comment: No physical WiFi switch. Thanks for the first option, waiting on any other suggestions.

Comment: The fact it's taking upwards of 5 minutes to return a response is very odd.  Having a multiple personal Windows 10 devices, I never encounter that sort of delay, when I incorrectly log into my local account which is connected to a MS account.

Comment: @Ramhound, Not sure why, but my internet connection is not always good. But in this case it would actually help, because it shouldn't be able to connect to the domain.

Answer (score 1):

Cancel windows login ony works with RDP.

For your situation there is no such option, but you can always disconnect the cable.

Answer (score 0):

Try to shutdown your internet connection from either a WiFi switch or any laptop has dedicatd funcional key to switch to airplane mode (Usually it can be turned off by pressing and holding `Fn` button and then press functional button that has antenna sign, usually it F8 but can be different depending on make and model)

In the cortana's search bar paste following string `rundll32.exe keymgr.dll,KRShowKeyMgr`, then this shameless lady should found : "**Stored User Names and Passwords Box**", highlight it and click Enter. You should get a window with saved credentials and one of them should be **Windows live**. On the right side you can choose appropriate action to that record (Remove/edit)